# adb shell sms attachment

Tags: android, shell, adb, attachment

This is all working great. However, how do you get the ADB SHELL to attach a picture to a MMS before sending it? Without using the keyevents, as it is not a good practice to do so. Tried to figure out how by Android system logs etc, without success. Thank you all!

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es 
sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Comment: you can't send anything but text with `SMS`. To send a message with media attachment you need to use `MMS`

Comment: MMS or SMS, it does open the same intent and you can attach a file manually then send it with or without text. I am wondering how to achieve this with the terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Kind of a "intent.action.AttachFile "/sdcard/test.jpg"

Comment: Or, There seems to be no such thing as the "Attach Icon" + "Select file" key events